# Unable to trigger popup box on click event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm wrapping up results of ajax request on div and appending to main div in a page. SO if the array of results returned empty, I would like to alert user, saying that no result found and also provide a link for them to click on. When they click a pop up box carrying products by category would popup. Important thing to notice here is,the products are derived via php and ajax scripts.

So When I use onclick event or  directly, nothing happens!!!. But if I call empty or HTML pop up it would work. Also the same php scripts contained pop up would work if I trigger it on page load or in the ajax success function. SO I dont understand why only with on click it doesn't work?

This is the pop up I want to trigger on 'click' event

```
 <section id="browse-search-popup" class="mfp-hide white-popup">
 <h1>Browse Courses</h1>
 <a href="">Can't find what you're looking for? Tell us here!</a>
 <h2>First, pick a learning Zone:</h2>
 <div class="row">
   <div class="small-12 medium-8 large-8 medium-centered large-centered columns">
       <ul class="small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-2">
       <?php
          $tutor =  new register();
          $data = $tutor->get_maincat();
          $i=0;
          foreach($data as $k=>$v)
          {
              $i++;
              ?>

              <li><div class="mainCat_<?php echo $i;?>" id="<?php echo $v['main_cat_id'];?>"><?php echo $v['main_cat_name'];?></div></li>

              <?php
          }
       ?>
       </ul>
   </div>
 </div>


<h2>Then, pick a field:</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns" id="cat">
    </div>
</div>

<h2>Finally, choose your Course:</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns" class="choosen_subjects">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns" id="sub">
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="done" value="Done">
 </section>
```

Ajax request

```
$("#search_tutor").submit(function() {
    var data = {
        "action": "test"
    };
    var subject = $("#subject").val();
    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/fetch_tutor.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#contents img.loading").remove();
            var sizy = data.length;
            if(sizy ==0) {
                console.log("sorry, cannot locate");
                $(".simply-popup-link").trigger("click");
                $("#simply-popup").empty();

                //This is where I want to trigger the on click
                $("#simply-popup").append("Unable to locate the subject you entered, please <a href='#'  onclick='browse("+sizy+")' class='yellow'>Browse</a>");

            }
            console.log("size= "+data.length);
            var j=0;
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                ........................
                ......................
```

The browse function:

```
function browse(param) {
    //this would work
    /* $(".simply-popup-link").trigger("click");
       $("#simply-popup").empty();
       $("#simply-popup").append("test only"); */

    // but not this
    $(".browse-search-popup-link").trigger("click");
}
```

I tried loading the page into the an empty popup box ($("#simply-popup")) like this but doesn't work either:

```
 $("#simply-popup").load('search/browse.php');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$("#simply-popup").append("Unable to locate the subject you entered, please <a href='#'  onclick='browse("+sizy+")' class='yellow'>Browse</a>");
```

to

```
$("#simply-popup").append("Unable to locate the subject you entered, please <a href='#' class='yellow browse'>Browse</a>");
```

write a separate code for this

```
$('body').on('click', '.browse', function() {
    $('.browse-search-popup-link').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just call that function after append:

```
$("#simply-popup").append("Unable to locate the subject.....");
browse(sizy);// call it here.
```

or when you append it in the element then you can call the click:

```
$("#simply-popup").append("Unable to locate the subject.....");
$("#simply-popup a").click();
```

```js
$(document.body).append('<a href="#" onclick="browse('+1+')">browse value is 1</a>');
$(document.body).find('a').click();

function browse(num){ $(document.body).find('p').html("<pre>"+num+"</pre>");}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
log out here:
<p></p>
```